# Django Connect remote Mysql OperationalError 2026

Tags: python, mysql, django, ssl, operationalerror

I'm using Django + mysql for days. And this morning I suddenly found that I cannot get connect with the remote mysql.

```
% python manage.py makemigrations
```

it raise

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed')`

also when

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Here's my environment:

macOS 10.15 + Django 2.2.6 + MySQL 5.7 (on a remote server, ubuntu 18.04) + python 3.6.8 (use conda env)

I've looked for some solutions like:

- downgrade openssl

  Package openssl conflicts for:
  openssl=1.0.2r
  python=3.6.8 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a']
- add use_pure=True in my .conf file

  > nothing changed
- add skip_ssl in my .conf file

  > nothing changed

### note

- On the server (which I deploy my site, ubuntu 18.04) my site run well using gunicorn + Nginx
- All the things worked well until today.
- The site broke when I found this issue but work well when I restart it.
- I guess maybe some update on the server (automatically upgrade) to cause the problem, but haven't find it yet.

### some of my code

```
# setting.py


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': mysqlPath,
            'init_command': 'SET default_storage_engine=INNODB',
        },
    }
}

# my_remote.cnf (which define the 'mysqlPath' in setting.py)

[client]
database = mydatabase
user = myusername
password = mypassword   
default-character-set = utf8
host = myremotehost
port = 3306
use_pure = True
skip-ssl
skip_ssl
skip-ssl = True
skip_ssl = True
```

Comment: the problem solved by adding `skip_ssl` in mysql conf and restart it; but still want to know why and will this method causes some problems?

Answer (score 0):

It is because your server isn't set up for SSL (yet). Thus, the error is caused on the server-side.

As already mentioned and tried successfully, a solution is to either make the server SSL-ready or set `skip_ssl` to `true` while in development.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-encrypted-connections.html